# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::index()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to learning Laravel but I'm having trouble routing to controller, I have a controller named "App" and I have a function named index in it, it says it can't find it in "App" controller even though I set it in the route

Error

> Error 
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::index()
> http://localhost:8000/anasayfa

***App.php***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class App extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return "anasayfa";
    }
}
```

***web.php***

```
Route::get('/anasayfa', 'App@index');
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Don't name your controller `App`, that name is already in use by Laravel

Answer (score 1):

A class with the name `App` already exists in Laravel, defined in namespace `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App`

if you want to use your class make sure to add

```
use  App\Http\Controllers\App
```

in your `web.php`

It is recommended to use a different name. You should follow the conventions and name it `AppController`.

Comment: Don't forget to add   ```use  App\Http\Controllers\AppController``` to web.php file

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved.

I deleted the controller named "App" and created a controller named "AppController". But this caused a new error, Laravel could not find class "AppController". For this I updated web.php as follows;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AppController;

Route::get('/anasayfa', [AppController::class, 'index']);
```